# Как перевести строку с датой в формат YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата

Есть специальный модуль календаря для tkinter под названием tkcalendar. При взятии данных из такого календаря, я получаю строку вида DD.MM.YYYY, но для БД на SQLite мне нужна строка вида YYYY-MM-DD. К сожалению модуль `dateutil.parser` не всегда переводит строку с датой верно. Например: я беру дату за сегодня, то получаю: `2020-03-18 00:00:00`, но если я возьму другую дату(`08.04.2004`), то на выход идёт мешанина: `2004-08-04 00:00:00`. Парсер почему-то неверно переводит DD.MM.YYYY в YYYY-MM-DD и иногда меняет месяц и день местами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, более точный парсер даты, который не будет допускать таких ошибок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте стандартный модуль `datetime` для парсинга строки и конвертирования:

```
import datetime as DT

dt = DT.datetime.strptime('10.11.2019', '%d.%m.%Y')
print(dt)
# 2019-11-10 00:00:00

print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
# 2019-11-10
```